# how to enable parent window scroll for g:DialogBox

Tags: gwt

`
i have gwt DialogBox that will open, once i click on button. mouse scroll is working only on open dialogBox, i would like to make it work for parent window as well. 
i tried by making modal="false" but no use. please help.

here is the sample code

```
<g:DialogBox autoHide="false" glassEnabled="true" modal="true" styleName="{style.historyGraphDialogPanel}">
    <g:HTMLPanel >
      <table class="HistoryGraphInteractionTable" ui:field="historyGraphInteractionTable">
        <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <g:Button ui:field="lastDay">Last Day</g:Button>
          <g:Button ui:field="lastWeek">Last Week</g:Button>
          <g:Button ui:field="lastMonth">Last Month</g:Button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <cdm:HistoryGraphWidget ui:field="graphWidget" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <g:Button ui:field="closeButton">Close</g:Button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

```
.historyGraphDialogPanel {
    background-color: ivory;        
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `modal` attribute is not working in ui.xml but setting modal in JAVA will solve your problem.

```
setModal(false);
```

---

Here is a sample code:

MyDialogbox.java:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiTemplate;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class MyDialogbox extends DialogBox {

    private static MyUiBinder myUIBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    @UiTemplate("MyDialogbox.ui.xml")
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyDialogbox> {
    }

    public MyDialogbox() {
        setWidget(myUIBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        this.setModal(false);
    }

    @UiField
    Button cancelButton;

    @UiHandler("cancelButton")
    void hideDialogBox(ClickEvent event) {
        hide();
    }

}
```

MyDialogbox.ui.xml:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

    <g:DialogBox autoHide="true" modal="false">
        <g:caption>
            <b>Caption text</b>
        </g:caption>
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            Body text
            <g:Button ui:field='cancelButton'>Cancel</g:Button>
            <g:Button ui:field='okButton'>Okay</g:Button>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:DialogBox>
</ui:UiBinder>
```